How to install pipewire-devel on Kubuntu 24.04
I am trying to build a small test program in order to experiment with PipeWire.
When trying to build using cmake I get the following error message:
Fatal error: spa/pod/builder.h: No such file or directoty
So I obviously need to install pipewire-devel and my questing is: how do I do that?
I am using Kubuntu 24.04 and my PipeWire version is 1.0.5.

Maybe a kubuntu forum would be a better place to ask that question :)
